# unable to display my product name and categories in url of codeigniter website

Tags: codeigniter

hi unable to display my product name and categories in url of codeigniter website

actually muy url is:  http://manimukta.com/search/details/738/5/5 like this

i want to make this url to  http://manimukta.com/Arts&Artifacts/Silver-Articles/Decoratives/Animal/Horse/738/5/5

can u please help me out

Comment: That ampersand will cause trouble if you don't escape it. And I think you're going to have a hard time getting what you want -- it's not how those paths work in CodeIgnitor. Are you trying to do this because of SEO?

Comment: ya exactly because of SEO i am trying to do this..i am new to this codeigniter  help me........

Comment: I cannot. I think you'd have to dig into CodeIgnitor and rewrite the internal controller(s) for page navigation. SEO is not all it's cracked up to be sometimes. This is one of those times.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `application` folder and in your config.php file change the `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`.

```
   $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:&_\-,()!$';
```

Comment: if i use this also its not changing anything and  please check my .htaccess file is          RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ manimukta.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: and my routes.php file is having only this                                                  .............. $route['default_controller'] = "welcome";

$route['404_override'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

You have to use codeigniter routing concept which is helped your question

for ex :

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = "search/detail";
```

In your url has product it will look up 'search' controller and 'detail' function

further detail refer below

```
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html
```

Comment: if i apply all these routes also it's not working do i need to write any functions

Comment: so how can i show these kind of URLs and if i change anything in routing also its not effecting